# How to search a URL on the web from a print command in python?

Tags: python, variables, url, search, printing

I have this kind of code:

```
site = 'google'
print("www.", site, ".com", sep="")
```

But then I like to search it on the web so:

```
import webbrowser
site = 'google'
url = ("www.", site, ".com", sep="")
webbrowser.open(url)
```

But it just doesn't work. It gives an error and it doesn't understand `sep=" "`

I hope it's possible to fix?

Comment: There's a huge difference between calling a function and making a tuple, parentheses notwithstanding. There are multiple ways to format and otherwise manipulate strings in Python (for printing or passing to any other function), you don't need this at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sep` is an argument for `print`. Not sure why you are using it by creating a URL tuple. That won't work. Please read about tuples and function parenthesis.
2. Read the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) to see an example of using the `webbrowser` module.

   ```
   webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')
   # OR
   url = "https://www." + site +".com"
   webbrowser.open(url)
   ```

Comment: Well thanks, I am quite new to this, so I need to learn the basics still.